# error_reporting(E_ALL); Says $key undefined

Tags: php

I enabled `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and its now saying that `$key` is undefined

```
// set md5 hash
$time = time();
$hash = md5($key . $time);
```

I never had to define it in the past, but with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` enabled im not sure if I have to define `$key` or not

Is it ok that it is undefined or is there a way to clear up this error?

Comment: `md5($key . $time)`.  You need to define `$key`, otherwise it's `NULL`.  If you're not going to define it, then why are you using it?

Comment: No it's not okay to have it undefined! You have to define it: e.g `$key = "xy";`

Comment: You can either define `$key` or take it out: `md5($time);`. Using a `$key` will just guarantee uniqueness of a hash such that no one else can make the same hash using a guess at your server's timestamp. See [salts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))

Comment: You surely need to define it. Why would you like to have junk values?

Comment: @sjagr it does generate unique hashes that cant be reversed, so is it fine to just leave it as is?

Comment: @JoeBobby The short and correct answer is: no!

Comment: No. And I can make the same salt. What if I guessed that you were using server time to make the hash? If I guessed that your server used the time of `1422473499`, I could easily use `md5(1422473499)` and now I have your exact hash. Guessing your salt (or in this case, `$key`) is a more difficult challenge. Why are you fighting something that's so easy to fix, by the way? Just define your damn `$key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not ok - you should define the variables you use. If it's not defined, it might be defined by, say, some other php script (assuming you have multiple in use, which is a common case).

The way to clear up the error is to define variables used.

Comment: i never had to define it in the past so I'm not sure what to define it with.  This only started when i used `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @JoeBobby no, it is only *showing* since you use that - before it's been hidden. It's certainly been there as long as you've used undefined variables. If you want to define it as empty string, then define it like `$key = '';`.